# Spring injected beans null in nested class

Tags: java, spring

I have a class with 2 static nested classes that do the same operation on 2 different generic types.

I exposed the 2 classes as beans and added @Autowired for the constructors as I usually do.

Here is the basic setup

```
abstract class <T> Parent implements MyInterface<T> {
   private final Service service;
   Parent(Service service){ this.service = service; }

   @Override public final void doInterfaceThing(T thing){
     T correctedT = map(thing);
     service.doTheThing(correctedT);
   }

   protected abstract T map(T t);

   @Service
   public static class ImplA extends Parent<A> {
     @Autowired ImplA (Service service){ super(service); }
     A map(A a){ //map a }
   }

   @Service
   public static class ImplB extends Parent<B> {
     @Autowired ImplB (Service service){ super(service); }
     B map(B b){ //map b }
   }

}
```

And in another class I have

```
@Service
public class Doer {
   private final List<MyInterface<A>> aImpls;
   @Autowired public Doer(List<MyInterface<A>> aImpls){ this.aImpls = aImpls; }
   public void doImportantThingWithA(A a){
     aImpls.get(0).doInterfaceThing(a);
   }
}
```

When I run the app, everything appears to be injected correctly and when I put a breakpoint in the ImplA and ImplB constructors, I have a not-null value for "service". I also have an ImplA bean in the aImpls list in Doer.

When I call doImportantThingWithA(a) however, "service" is null inside ImplA and I obviously die.

I'm not sure how this is possible because:

1. I see a nonnull value in my constructors for service which is a final field.
2. If spring is injecting ImplA and ImplB into another class, it should already have either injected a Service into ImplA or ImplB, or thrown an exception on bean initialization. I have nothing set to lazily load and all bean dependencies are required.

The reason for the nested classes is because the only thing that changes between the 2 implementations is the map() function. Trying to avoid extra classes for 1 line of varying code.

**More info:**
When I add a breakpoint in Parent.doInterfaceThing(), if I add a watch on "service" I get null as the value. If I add a getService() method, and then call getService() instead of referring directly to this.service, I get the correct bean for service. I don't know the implications of this but something seems weird with the proxying.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question, but why don't you just create two mapper beans, i. e. compose rather than inherit?

Comment: @daniu Was trying to avoid creating 2 new files when they only vary by 1 line of code. I definitely will do that though if I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: try to get a direct reference to an instance of ImplA in the constructor. If it fails to autowire, you know your context configuration is incorrect and not instantiating that service. You won't get autowire failures when the injected bean is a list

Comment: @Taugenichts I am able to directly inject an instance of ImplA successfully. I assume this means spring was correctly able to find Service bean for injection?

Comment: @TylerHelmuth yes. Does it work if you also try injecting with List<Parent<A>> as well? If so it would seem you may need to file a bug with Spring about not properly resolving inherited interfaces. To force it to work, you could also try adding implements MyInterface<A> (even though it's redundant) onto the definition of ImplA.

Comment: @Taugenichts I am definitely able to inject List<Parent<A>> successfully. I added implements MyInterface<A> onto ImplA but I still have null as the value of service.

What I did find is what I added in More Info: in the question. The value of the service field is always null, but calling a getService() method gives me the correct bean. I don't know really how the proxying works but it seems like something is weird there.

Comment: @TylerHelmuth can you share the code for the Service bean since that is what is actually null? I was initially misunderstanding where the npe was occurring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173772/discussion-between-tyler-helmuth-and-taugenichts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what is causing the issue is Parent.doInterfaceThing();

If I remove final from the method signature, "service" field is correctly populated and the code works as expected.

I don't understand at all why changing a method signature affects the injected value of final fields in my class... but it works now.

Comment: Because a proxy is being made, a class based proxy to be exact. A `final` method cannot be proxied and thus the method will be available on the proxy (which doesn't have anything wired) instead of passing it on to the instance the proxy wraps (which does have the auto wiring).

Comment: Ah ok and I can see the field when I call getService() because that will call through to the actual bean instance which can see the "service" field?

Answer (score 0):

What I meant with my "use mappers" comment was something like this:

```
class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
   @Autowired
   private final Service service;

   @Override public final <T> void doInterfaceThing(T thing, UnaryOperator<T> mapper){
     T correctedT = mapper.apply(thing);
     service.doTheThing(correctedT);
   }

   // new interface to allow autowiring despite type erasure
   public interface MapperA extends UnaryOperator<A> {
     public A map(A toMap);
     default A apply(A a){ map(a); }
   }
   @Component
   static class AMapper implements MapperA {
       public A map(A a) { // ... }
   }

   public interface MapperB extends UnaryOperator<B> {
     public B map(B toMap);
     default B apply(B b){ map(b); }
   }
   @Component
   static class BMapper implements MapperB {
       public B map(B a) { // ... }
   }
}
```

This does have a few more lines than the original, but not much; however, you do have a better Separation of Concern. I do wonder how autowiring works in your code with the generics, it does look as if that might cause problems.

Your client would look like this:

```
@Service
public class Doer {
   private final List<MapperA> aMappers;
   private final MyInterface myInterface;
   @Autowired public Doer(MyInterface if, List<MapperA> mappers){ 
       this.myInterface = if;
       this.aImpls = mappers; }
   public void doImportantThingWithA(A a){
     aMappers.stream().map(m -> m.map(a)).forEach(myInterface::doInterfaceThing);
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't quite align with the logic I'm trying to get accomplished because of the way I simplified my code. The mapping is also just a small implementation detail specific to this Parent implentation. I have other things that implement MyInterface which don't need any mapping so I don't want to bring that into Doer. As far as generics spring 4 added the ability to wire based on generic type.